# how to view GCP HealthCheck logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a Health Check in my GCP project for http traffic. I wanted to see the logs in Cloud Logging but I cant see any logs related to the created HealthCheck. I have logging enabled in HealthCheck. Can anyone help me?

I have checked in Cloud Logging and filter on gcp_health_check resources but no luck..

Note: this health check is for public api server.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentations for health checks [1] and for HTTP load balancing here [2]. Review them and see which one is more suitable for you.

Have a nice day!

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-logging

[2] - https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring

Comment: Thank you sharing this.
One query here(Might be silly, excuse me for that).. Do health checks produce logs for only when any error comes/health check fails or it will also produce logs even if health check are being passed? I know that Health checks generate a log whenever an endpoint changes state from one state to another but if since i have configured my HC there is no change in state of endpoints(they are in healthy state since they configured). will there be any logs(any type of)

Comment: As mentioned in the first link "Logs are generated for endpoint health transition only." so only logs are generated for error and for when they become healthy.